# What does the MATLAB function norm() do?

Tags: matlab, normalization

As far as I know, `norm(X)` is used to calculate the 2-norm of a matrix `X`.

Also in the documentation, it says `norm(X)` approximates to `max(svd(X))`, and they do have the same results.

However, why those two calculations do not equal since they are all Euclidean norm?

```matlab
m = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9];
norm(m)  % 16.8481
sum(m.^2, 'all').^0.5  % 16.8819
```

Comment: As you already mentioned, the documentation says norm(X) approximates to max(svd(X)), which by definition means they do NOT have same results!
The documentation also distinguishes between the 2-norm of vectors and matrices. The 2 norm of a vector is the euclidean norm and represents the length of a vector in an euclidean space. So when calculation the euclidean norm of a vector the calculation norm(v)=sum(v.^2)^0.5 is appropriate. Whereas for matrices it isn't. Instead norm(m) is calculation the maximum singular value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) representing the 2 norm.

Comment: @mattesyo: That looks like a complete answer. Please consider posting it as such.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned, the documentation says norm(X) approximates to max(svd(X)), which by definition means they do NOT have same results! The documentation also distinguishes between the 2-norm of vectors and matrices. The 2 norm of a vector is the euclidean norm and represents the length of a vector in an euclidean space. So when calculating the euclidean norm of a vector the calculation norm(v)=sum(v.^2)^0.5 is appropriate. Whereas for matrices it isn't. Instead norm(m) is calculation the maximum singular value (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value) representing the 2 norm.